# LWUIT Localize MenuBar

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, menubar

I'd like to localize the `MenuBar` of an LWUIT `form`.

I don't want to show the users "Menu" / "Select" / "Cancel".

I've successfully localized single commands, which get shown when the Menu opens,
via

```
back.setCommandName("bk");
searchCommand.setCommandName("search");
exit.setCommandName("ex");

mainMenu.addCommand(back, 0);
mainMenu.addCommand(searchCommand, 1);
mainMenu.addCommand(exit, 2);
```

For the `MenuBar` I tried

```
MenuBar m = NameOfMyForm.getMenuBar();

m.setName("test");
mainMenu.setMenuBar(m);
```

But this didn't work - also this wouldn't give me access to "Select" and "Cancel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setResourceBundle()` method. See the code for change the menu, select and cancel command captions.

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put("select", "your caption");
hashtable.put("cancel", "your caption");
hashtable.put("menu", "your caption");
UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(hashtable);
```

Suppose if you want to use image for these commands means use `setMenuIcons` method,

```
UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setMenuIcons(Image select, Image cancel, Image menu)
```