# How to change the text of select & cancel command in lwuit

Tags: lwuit

Hi I am developing mobile apps using Lwuit 1.5
my app contains 3 language so I am doing a localization and I'm using the next code for localization:
(String) local.get("any text ")
& it work just fine with any component
but the problem is that it doesn't work with the select & cancel softbutton
I tried to use .setSelectCommandText but it also doesn't work
So could anybody help me on how to change the select & cancel text
& Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Use setResourceBundle() method. See the oiginal answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938731/lwuit-localize-menubar).

Answer (score 0):

Use the strings `"select"` and `"cancel"` lower case with the `setResourceBundle()` method of the `UIManager`.